# Twitch.tv does not work, Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, flash

I started playing around with the Lubuntu I managed to install yesterday. Everything is great so far, but I ran into one problem. Twitch.tv does not work (in Mozilla Firefox).

The player is black, it seems like it does not even attempt loading, if I switch to fullscreen, the loading icon appears, but nothing ever loads. I am aware of livestreamer, but I'd like to watch in Mozilla.

I tried installing pipelight and enabling Adobe Flash player, but it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, livestreamer will dramatically reduce both CPU and RAM usage while watching twitch.tv streams. This, you should be aware of and it should be enough alone to convince you to use VLC. I'm not here to lecture though...

To fix it, you need the Flash plugin for Firefox - the Adobe Flash Player you have installed I believe will be a system plugin and might not work. The official site should offer you an appropriate flash plugin which you can download and install: https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ - visit it from Firefox and it should suggest the browser plugin.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am aware that livestreamer is a great tool and I most likely will be using it, however I know that I will need to watch livestreams on the twitch website in the future, so I wanted to get this out of the way. How do I mark your answer as the correct one, or make this question closed?

Comment: Ehm, you can't mark this because it's a comment - I'll make a proper reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've installed Flash on your system, but this does not enable the Firefox Flash plugin, meaning that any websites you visit within firefox won't be able to use it.

To get Flash for Firefox itself, you can visit http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer - installing this will enable you to use Flash websites properly.